# Making a encoding thing not sure why its not working - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

Hey i'm making a string encoder not sure why its not working here's the code. I have no idea whats wrong with it can someone explain whats wrong and how i can fix it?

What i want it to do is when you give it a input it goes to a list
and gets the next letter
eg.
["a","b","c","d", etc..]
ab would become bc

index.js

```
const data = require('./data.json');
module.exports = (txt, amount, Inlist) => {
    if (txt === "" || txt === undefined || txt === null ||
    isNaN(amount) === true || amount === undefined || amount === null) {
        console.log("[ApiModule-Encode] No input or amount.")
        return
    }
    if (Inlist == undefined) {
        list = "default"
    } else {
        list = Inlist
    }
    function encode(txt) {
        text = txt
        let ans
        let i = 0
        while (i < text.length) {
            let char = text.charAt(i)
            let charNum
            if ( data[list].indexOf(char) == text.length ) {
                charNum = 0
            } else {
                charNum = parseInt(data[list].indexOf(char)) + 1
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                ans = data[list][charNum]
            } else {
                ans = ans + data[list][charNum]
            }
            i++
        }
        return ans
    }
    let i = 0
    let curans
    while (i <= amount) {
        if (i == 0) {
            curans = encode(txt)
        } else {
            curans = curans + encode(curans)
        }
        i++
    }
    return curans
}
```

data.json

```
{
    "default": [
        "a", "b", "c", 
        "d", "e", "f",
        "g", "h", "i",
        "j", "k", "l",
        "m", "n", "o",
        "p", "q", "r",
        "s", "t", "u",
        "v", "w", "x",
        "y", "z",
        "0", 0,
        "1", 1,
        "2", 2,
        "3", 3,
        "4", 4,
        "5", 5,
        "6", 6,
        "7", 7,
        "8", 8,
        "9", 9,
        " ", "!", "@",
        "#", "$", "%",
        "^", "&", "*",
        "(", ")",
        "[", "]",
        "<", ">",
        ",", ".",
        "/", "?", ":",
        ";", "'", "\\",
        "|", "-", "_",
        "=", "+", "`",
        "~"
    ]
}
```

---

test.js

```
const encode = require("./index.js")
encode("e", 1)
```

Then when i node test.js

```
PS C:\**removed**> node index
fg
```

Thank you.
*If you need anymore info please tell me.*

Comment: Seems like you need to split the `txt`. You are accepting 1 value in the parameter and no-where you are splitting it.

Comment: @LV98 Where do i need to split it in my code?

Comment: Your parameter `txt`